# Column is invalid in the select list due to it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the order count by each month each year, I found that there are several related functions which is helpful.

First are datepart(M, OrderDate), datepart(Y, OrderDate), so I wrote my code as follows:

```
select DATEPART(Q, OrderDate) Q , datepart(YEAR, OrderDate) Y, count(*) count 
from Orders 
group by DATEPART(Q, OrderDate), datepart(Y, OrderDate);
```

but it has error:
Column 'Orders.OrderDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Then, I tried to use Month(DateOrder), and Year(DateOrder) and the code is as follows:

```
select month(OrderDate) M , year(OrderDate) y, count(*) count 
from Orders 
group by month(OrderDate),year(OrderDate);
```

the result of the above code shows it is success.

My question is why the first code has error but the second code is correct? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly a confusion because `Q` is a keyword in SQL Server.

Comment: You should avoid using date part shorthand anyway. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in SELECT you have used `datepart(YEAR, OrderDate)` searching for **YEAR** part, and in group by you have `datepart(Y, OrderDate)` - **Y** is not short from YEAR but actually stand for DayOfYear

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql

Short for Year is YY

Query would work as :

```
select DATEPART(Q, OrderDate) Q , datepart(YEAR, OrderDate) Y, count(*) count 
from Orders 
group by DATEPART(Q, OrderDate), datepart(YY, OrderDate);
```

You can see in this **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/69008/2)** - using `YY` will give 2017 for today, using `Y` will give 230 - as it's 230th day in this year

Comment: Upvoted, but please test Gordon's hypothesis as well.  Could be multiple problems.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Tested, naming column `Q` and/or using `Q` in Datepart make no problems